# How to preserve data disk from a generalized Azure RM VM image

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-storage

I've created an Azure RM VM image of Windows 2008 R2 with SQL Server 2014 installed.  The image was created with a data disk where I placed the SQL Server data directory (location for the system databases, error logs etc).  The image was sysprepped then generalized, all successfully.

I created a new VM from the above image, pointing to the OS and data disk URIs.  The VM gets created but I have to go into Computer Management > Disk Management and provision the drive from the presented volume.  Since SQL Server's startup process is looking for the errorlogs, system databases etc, which do not exist there, it's basically a failed install.

Is there a way to preserve the data on the data disk, then provision that into Windows, programatically?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to preserve the data on the data disk, then provision
>   that into Windows, programatically?

Yes, you could. You could use Azure PowerShell to create an image of a generalized Azure VM. You can then use the image to create another VM. The image includes the OS disk and the data disks that are attached to the virtual machine. I have tested in my lab, it works for me.

```
 Stop-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName shuitest1 -Name shui -Force
 Set-AzureRmVm -ResourceGroupName shuitest1 -Name shui -Generalized
 $vm = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName shuitest1 -Name shui -Status
 $vm.Statuses
 Save-AzureRmVMImage -ResourceGroupName shuitest1 -Name shui -DestinationContainerName "shuitest" -VHDNamePrefix "shuitest"  -Path "D:\Filename.json"
```

More information about how to capture a VM image from a generalized Azure VM please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-capture-image).

You could use the image(contains OS disk and data disks but no virtual network in it) to deploy your VM. More information about how to **create a VM from a generalized managed VM image** please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-create-vm-generalized-managed?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Fwindows%2Ftoc.json).

Also, you could use local json file to deploy your VM, you need to create a NIC on Azure Portal. If you use the way to deploy VM, the VM does not have  a Public IP, you need to add it manual. I test in my lab, it works for me. If possible, I suggest you use local json file to redeploy your VM. The following is my cmdlet.

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ExampleDeployment -ResourceGroupName shuitest1 -TemplateFile "D:\Filename.json"
```

[image]

Comment: The instructions you posted were the ones I followed.  I wasn't able to deploy using `code` New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $location -VM $vm `code` (after building the $vm) because it kept timing out.  So, I went with your second suggestion of deploying from a template.  I added the NIC and security group to the template and a private IP (we have an Express Route set up).  Did I miss some syntax in the template that makes the data disk visible in Windows?

Comment: Here's the template (I edited the URIs, replacing with <storage account>.  The template deployed successfully so ignore any potential syntax problems in those URIs): [link](http://expressnetsolutions.com/sqldch/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/template.txt)

Comment: No, I posted the template I used, following the links you supplied.  It doesn't provision the data disk useful to Windows, unfortunately.

Comment: When you create VM by using template, could you find data disk on Azure Portal? I test in my lab, I could find it.

Comment: I created a new image and template, it kept the disks this time except changed the drive letters.  I'd set the image up with M:, L: and T:, it reverted to F:, G: and H:.  But instead of trying to do a full install of SQL Server, i chose instead to only prepare a(n) SQL image then finalize the install when I create VMs from the image.

Comment: Yes, changed drive to letters to match my architecture.  But it's a configuration change that I was hoping to not have to do, as I'd set up the VM the way I wanted in the first place.  Thanks for your replies.